# For what copulative verbs is the nominative case used in addition to est?

Tags: classical-latin

I'm a real beginner, but I was reading that a noun is declined as nominative for the predicative nominative, so:

cattus est canis,
the cat is a dog

both cat and dog would be declined in the nominative case.

but I was curious if both nouns would be declined in the nominative if there were another copulative verb, e.g.:

the cat looks like a dog

would they both be declined in the nominative? or is the only verb this applies to est? sorry, I know this is probably very obvious, but like I said, beginner. thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides "to be", another verb that acts this way is *videor*, "to seem" or "appears", which does work as a translation to "looks like" depending on how you use it. (It looks like a dog = I'm not sure what it is but it looks like a dog = It appears to be a dog).

Cicero's *De Officiis* provides a nice example of this usage:

> Numquam...imbelles timidique videamur.
>
> We must never seem powerless and cowardly.

Both *imbelles* and *timidi* are nominative, and the subject is an implied *nos*.

If you were to switch it out for *simus*, the grammar would not change.

If you means "looks like" as in "resemble," the Latin construction uses *similis* instead, which takes a genitive or a dative, not a nominative.

Answer (score 5):

In general, verbs that *equate* two things put the same case on either side of the verb. For example, *vocāre* "call" in the active can equate two things in the accusative (i.e. two direct objects), and in the passive equates two things in the nominative. For a few examples from Ennius (since he shows up first in my corpus search):

> Istic est is Iuppiter quem dico, **quem** Graeci vocant **aerem**…
> *It is this Jupiter that I speak of, whom the Greeks call "aer"…*

> Deinde Pan eum deducit in montem, **qui** vocatur caeli **stela**.
> *Then Pan led him to a mountain, which is called the Pillar of Heaven.*

Similar verbs like *appellāre* work the same way, this time quoting Caesar:

> …tertiam [incolunt] **qui** ipsorum lingua **Celtae**, nostra **Galli** appellantur.
> *The third territory is inhabited by those who are called "Celts" in their own language and "Gauls" in ours.*

> …in his Diviciaco et Lisco […] **quem Vergobretum** appellant Haedui…
> *…among these were Diviciacus and Liscus […] whom the Haedui call "Vergobret"…*